# Analizador lexico, crear contadores de letras, numeros, espacios

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield, contador

Buenas tardes amigos de stackOverflow,
Mi problema es el siguiente, Estoy desarrollando un analizador léxico, el cual al introducir carácteres dentro de un área de texto, determina el número de carácteres que se encuentran dentro. Mi problema es que, pude hacer facilmente el contador de carácteres general y estoy teniendo problemas específicamente para hacer los demás(los mencionados en el título), si me pueden brindar ayuda para crear al menos uno, podría tomar orientación para crear el resto. Muchas gracias.

```
private void areaTextKeyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){ //Funcion KeyPress contador
    int contadorGeneral = 0;
    contadorGeneral = areaText.getText().length()+1;
    label2.setText(String.valueOf(contadorGeneral));
   
}
```

Éste es el único contador que poseo.

Answer (score 1):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class AyudaStack implements KeyListener {
private final JFrame ventana;
private final JLabel label;
private final JTextArea area;

   AyudaStack(){
  
   ventana=new JFrame();
   ventana.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   ventana.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
   ventana.setVisible(true);
   label=new JLabel();
   area=new JTextArea(20,20);
   area.addKeyListener(this);
   ventana.add(label);
   ventana.add(area);}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
label.setText(area.getText());
System.out.println(label.getText().length());}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    
}
   


}
```

Te dejo ese codigo amigo,espero que te sirva.Lo que hice fue crear una ventana con un label y un textarea.Implemento la interfaz KeyListener y se lo añado al area de texto.Al introducir caracteres en este,el label toma lo escrito en el textarea y lo establece como texto.Luego para obtener la cantidad de caracteres agarro el label y con el metodo lenght obtengo la cantidad de caracteres que este tiene

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Contador de numeros
        String numeros = scanValues.replaceAll("(?i)[^0-9]", "");
        int contador_numero = numeros.length();
        contadorNum.setText(String.valueOf(contador_numero));
        
        //Contador de letras
        String letras = scanValues.replaceAll("(?i)[^a-zA-Z]", "");
        int contador_letra = letras.length();
        contadorLetras.setText(String.valueOf(contador_letra));
        
        //Contador blanco
        String blanco = scanValues.replaceAll("(?i)[^\\s]", "");
        int contador_blanco = blanco.length();
        contadorEspacio.setText(String.valueOf(contador_blanco));
        
        //Contador simbolos
        String simbolo = scanValues.replaceAll("(?i)[\\sa-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        int contador_simbolo = simbolo.length();
        contadorSim.setText(String.valueOf(contador_simbolo));
```

Estos serían los demás contadores